# LiveData crash: Transformation to Map crash

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have the following code:

```
private var bookmarkDetailsView: LiveData<BookmarkDetailsView>? = null

private fun mapBookmarkToBookmarkView(bookmarkId: Long) {
    val bookmark = bookmarkRepo.getLiveBookmark(bookmarkId)
    bookmarkDetailsView = Transformations.map(bookmark) { repoBookmark ->
    repoBookmark?.let { repoBookmark ->
          bookmarkToBookmarkView(repoBookmark)
    }
  }
}
```

Since `Transformation` is `deprecated`, I am using `Map`

```
private fun mapBookmarkToBookmarkView(bookmarkId: Long) {
    val bookmark = bookmarkRepo.getLiveBookmark(bookmarkId)
     bookmarkDetailsView = bookmark.map { repoBookmark ->
         bookmarkToBookmarkView(repoBookmark)
    }
}
```

However, as soon the Bookmark is deleted from the database, I get the following crash:

```
E FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: com.raywenderlich.placebook, PID: 6512 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.raywenderlich.placebook.viewmodel.BookmarkDetailsViewModel$mapBookmarkToBookmarkView$1.invoke, parameter kausi_repoBookmark at com.raywenderlich.placebook.viewmodel.BookmarkDetailsViewModel$mapBookmarkToBookmarkView$1.invoke(Unknown Source:2)
at com.raywenderlich.placebook.viewmodel.BookmarkDetailsViewModel$mapBookmarkToBookmarkView$1.invoke(BookmarkDetailsViewModel.kt:50)
at androidx.lifecycle.Transformations$map$1.invoke(Transformations.kt:52) 
at androidx.lifecycle.Transformations$map$1.invoke(Transformations.kt:52)  at androidx.lifecycle.Transformations$sam$androidx_lifecycle_Observer$0.onChanged(Unknown Source:2)
at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.onChanged(MediatorLiveData.java:171)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)  
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)  
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)  
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:93)  
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8128)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:946
```

What am I doing wrong?  An explanation would be lovely.

**UPDATE**

```
fun getLiveBookmark(bookmarkId: Long): LiveData<Bookmark> = bookmarkDao.loadLiveBookmark(bookmarkId)

@Query("SELECT * FROM Bookmark WHERE id =:bookmarkId")
fun loadLiveBookmark(bookmarkId: Long): LiveData<Bookmark>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I made the following change:

```
fun getLiveBookmark(bookmarkId: Long): LiveData<Bookmark?> = bookmarkDao.loadLiveBookmark(bookmarkId)
```

Now I am getting another error:

```
private fun mapBookmarkToBookmarkView(bookmarkId: Long) {
    val bookmark = bookmarkRepo.getLiveBookmark(bookmarkId)
    if (bookmark != null) {
        bookmarkDetailsView = bookmark.map { repoBookmark ->
            repoBookmark?.let { // error is on this line
                bookmarkToBookmarkView(it)
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is BookmarkDetailsViewModel.BookmarkDetailsView? but BookmarkDetailsViewModel.BookmarkDetailsView was expected
```

Comment: What type does `bookmarkRepo.getLiveBookmark(bookmarkId)`? It seems like it is returning a `LiveData<Bookmark>` e.g., the object you get from that LiveData is always non-null (otherwise, the type would be `LiveData<Bookmark?>`). Can you include that part of your `BookmarkRepo`?

Comment: Thanks - I have updated it with the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared your LiveData object as a `LiveData<Bookmark>` which means that `map` and other transformations assume they are only going to receive a `Bookmark` - e.g., a non-null object. This wasn't a "problem" when using `Transformations.map` because Java doesn't care about nullability - but Kotlin does.

Therefore if you want to have your repository return a LiveData that can return a null bookmark, then you need to change the type your repository returns to use `LiveData<Bookmark?>` - a nullable type.

The same would apply to your `LiveData<BookmarkDetailsView>` - perhaps it should also be a `LiveData<BookmarkDetailsView?>` if you want to support nullable entries there as well.

Comment: Thanks - I am now getting another error. See Update 2

Comment: Did you change the type of your `bookmarkDetailsView` to be a `LiveData<BookmarkDetailsView?>` like the last line of my answer says? That error is saying the result of your `map` needs to be a `BookmarkDetailsView` (non-nullable) if your `LiveData` is a `LiveData<BookmarkDetailsView>` (non-nullable generic type).

Comment: Yes.  `private var bookmarkDetailsView: LiveData<BookmarkDetailsView>? = null` was always an optional.

Comment: You aren't looking at where the question mark is - if it is inside the `<>`, then it applies to the type the LiveData holds. When it is outside the `<>`, it applies to the LiveData object itself. You need it inside the `<>` if you want to store a null value (e.g., what your `map` returns when `repoBookmark` is null) in it.

Comment: aahh - I had to put it the question mark inside and outside to get it going.  Thank you for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

Use below to make your computed result `non-null`, as using `let` with `?` infers that some elements could be `null`

```
bookmark.mapNotNull { repoBookmark -> bookmarkToBookmarkView(repoBookmark) }
```

Comment: I believe `mapNotNull` requires a `List`.  `Bookmark` is a `LiveData<Bookmark?>`, not a `List`